# Find Groups by multiple cascadingly related conditions

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

### Problem

I have some data. I would like to flag the same instance (e.g. a person, company, machine, whatever) in my data by a unique ID. The data actually has some IDs but they are either not always present or one instance has different IDs.

What I try to acheive is to use these IDs along with individual information to find the same instance and assign a unique ID to them.

I found a solution, but this one is **highly inefficient**. I would appreciate both tipps to improve the performance of my code or - probably more promising - another approach.

### Code

#### Example Data

```
dt1 <- data.table(id1 = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                  id2 = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "D"),
                  surname = "Smith",
                  firstname = c("John", "John", "Joe", "Joe", "Jack"))
dt1
#>    id1 id2 surname firstname
#> 1:   1   A   Smith      John
#> 2:   1   B   Smith      John
#> 3:   2   A   Smith       Joe
#> 4:   3   C   Smith       Joe
#> 5:   4   D   Smith      Jack
```

#### Current Solution

```
find_grp <- function(dt,
                     by) {
  
  # keep necessary variables only
  dtx <- copy(dt)[, .SD, .SDcols = c(unique(unlist(by)))]
  
  # unique data.table to improve performance
  dtx <- unique(dtx)
  
  # assign a row id column
  dtx[, ID := .I]
  
  # for every row and every by group, find all rows that match each row 
  # on at least one condition
  res <- lapply(X   = dtx$ID,
                FUN = function(i){
                  unique(unlist(lapply(X = by, 
                                       FUN = function(by_sub) {
                                         merge(dtx[ID == i, ..by_sub],
                                               dtx,
                                               by = by_sub,
                                               all = FALSE)$ID
                                       }
                  )))
                })
  res
  
  print("merge done")
  
  # keep all unique matching rows
  l <- unique(res)
  
  # combine matching rows together, if there is at least one overlap between 
  # two groups.
  # repeat until all row-groups are completely disjoint form one another
  repeat{
    l1 <- l
    iterator <- seq_len(length(l1))
    for (i in iterator) {
      for (ii in iterator[-i]) {
        # is there any overlap between both row-groups
        if (length(intersect(l1[[i]], l1[[ii]])) > 0) {
          l1[[i]] <- sort(union(l1[[i]], l1[[ii]]))
        }
      }
    }
    if (isTRUE(all.equal(l1, l))) {
      break
    } else {
      l <- unique(l1)
    }
  }
  print("repeat done")
  
  # use result to assign a groupId to the helper data.table
  Map(l,
      seq_along(l),
      f = function(ll, grp) dtx[ID %in% ll, ID_GRP := grp])
  
  # remove helper Id
  dtx[, ID := NULL]
  
  # assign the groupId to the original data.table
  dt_out <- copy(dt)[dtx,
                     on = unique(unlist(by)),
                     ID_GRP := ID_GRP]
  
  return(dt_out[])
}
```

#### Result

```
find_grp(dt1, by = list("id1",
                        "id2"
                        , c("surname", "firstname"))
)
#> [1] "merge done"
#> [1] "repeat done"
#>    id1 id2 surname firstname ID_GRP
#> 1:   1   A   Smith      John      1
#> 2:   1   B   Smith      John      1
#> 3:   2   A   Smith       Joe      1
#> 4:   3   C   Smith       Joe      1
#> 5:   4   D   Smith      Jack      2
```

As you can see, `ID_GRP` is identified because

- the first two rows share `id1`
- since `id2` for `id1` contains `A`, row 3 with `id2 = A` belongs to the same group.
- finally, all `Joe Smith` belong to the same group as well because its the name in row 3
- so on and so forth
- only row 5 is completely unrelated

**`{data.table}` solutions are preferred**

Comment: If the second row had been "Mike Brown" (but with id1=1), would it still be in group 1? that is, do the ID variables "override", the name variables?

Comment: there is no overwrite but only cascading and including "markers". Same id1 --> same individual, same id2 as any row already assigned  --> same individual, same name as any row already assigned--> same individual

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. I'm not sure if I've completely understood your question. I've written a function (`gen_grp()`, that takes a data table `d`, and a vector of variables `v`. It steps through each unique `id1`, and replaces `id1` values if matches of certain types are found.

```
gen_grp <- function(d,v) {
  for(id in unique(d$id1)) {
    d[id2 %in% d[id1==id,id2], id1:=id]
    k=unique(d[id1==id, ..v])[,t:=id]
    d = k[d, on=v][!is.na(t), id1:=t][, t:=NULL]
  }
  
  d[, grp:=rleid(id1)]
  return(d[])
}
```

Usage:

```
gen_grp(dt1,c("surname","firstname"))
```

Output:

```
   surname firstname   id1    id2   grp
    <char>    <char> <num> <char> <int>
1:   Smith      John     1      A     1
2:   Smith      John     1      B     1
3:   Smith       Joe     1      A     1
4:   Smith       Joe     1      C     1
5:   Smith      Jack     4      D     2
```

Comment: Thank you for your Input. It is actually quite fast. However, it is not exactly working since, if you change `id2` of  the last row to `C`, all should belong to the same group, i.e. all instances share at east one common id/marker. 
The actual result is `c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2)`